# Conda won't remove package

Tags: anaconda

Am I doing something wrong in my commands?  I can't remove Keras.

```
$ conda remove --name myEnv keras
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - keras


$ conda list --name myEnv keras
# packages in environment at /Users/me/anaconda3/envs/myEnv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
keras                     2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The channel `pypi` for `keras` means you have mix used `pip` and `conda`. To uninstall the `keras` installed from `pypi`, use `pip`.

```sh
pip uninstall keras
```

It's not a good idea to mix use both package managers `pip` and `conda` in one environment. If you really need to. Read the official guide [Using Pip in a Conda Environment](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/).

Answer (score 3):

### Pip Interoperability

[As @Simba correctly identified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58406049/570918), the package is from PyPI (i.e., it was installed via `pip`). By default, Conda can recognize the presence of such packages but will not interact with them. However, there is a "preview" configuration option, `pip_interop_enabled`, that enables such interaction (see [Conda v4.6 Release Notes](https://www.anaconda.com/conda-4-6-release/)). You could either

1. Set this option globally:

   ```
   conda config --set pip_interop_enabled true
   conda remove --name myEnv keras
   ```

   If you have PyPI packages generally, then this should help improve your env stability, but at the cost of slightly longer solve times, since now Conda will account for packages coming from PyPI.
2. Temporarily turn it on just for this operation

   ```
   CONDA_PIP_INTEROP_ENABLED=1 conda remove --name myEnv keras
   ```

Comment: I've gotten further than vanilla remove. It's removed all of the packages needed for compatibility, but it didn't remove the package in question. I don't understand why python's package management is so broken compared to other languages.

Comment: @chaostheory where is it actually installed? Sounds like it might be leaking in from a user-site or possibly PYTHONPATH, which Conda won’t manage. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/70958434/570918

Answer (score 1):

```
conda remove --force (the rest of the command)
```

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/remove.html#Solver%20Mode%20Modifiers) say :"Forces removal of a package without removing packages that depend on it. Using this option will usually leave your environment in a broken and inconsistent state."