# Unexpected Python paths in Conda environment

Tags: python, path, conda

In a Conda environment (`base` here), I'm surprised by the order of directories in the Python path:

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', 
'/export/projects/III-data/wcmp_bioinformatics/db291g/miniconda3/lib/python37.zip',
'/export/projects/III-data/wcmp_bioinformatics/db291g/miniconda3/lib/python3.7',
'/export/projects/III-data/wcmp_bioinformatics/db291g/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
'/export/home/db291g/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
'/export/projects/III-data/wcmp_bioinformatics/db291g/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

As you can see, my local non-Conda path:

```
/export/home/db291g/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

comes before the Conda counterpart:

```
/export/projects/III-data/wcmp_bioinformatics/db291g/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

This means that Python packages installed in `miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages` will be ignored if they are also found in `.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`. In fact, in `.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` I have `numpy` v1.20, but in the Conda environment I need v1.19, which is correctly installed, but superseded by v1.20. This seems to defeat the point of using Conda.

Is there something wrong with my configuration or am I missing something here?

Some info:

```
which python
/export/projects/III-data/wcmp_bioinformatics/db291g/miniconda3/bin/python

python -V
Python 3.7.12

which conda
/export/projects/III-data/wcmp_bioinformatics/db291g/miniconda3/bin/conda

conda --version
conda 4.11.0
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is expected behavior (see [PEP 370](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/)) and partially why [Anaconda recommended against user-level package installations](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment).

[The `site` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#module-site) is responsible for setting the `sys.path` when Python is initializing. [The code in `site.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e480def027b68a570dc0c2e235463842373dc741/Lib/site.py#L603) specifically appends the user site prior to appending the prefix site, which is what leads to this prioritization. The motivation according to [PEP 370](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/) is that users would have a Python installed at system-level, but want to prioritize packages they install at the user level, hence the user site should load prior to the prefix site.

### Options

There are several options for avoiding the user-level site-packages from getting loaded.

#### 1: Environment variable

The environment variable `PYTHONNOUSERSITE` will toggle loading of user-level `site-packages`. Namely,

```bash
PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1 python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
```

#### 2: Python `-s` flag

Alternatively, the Python binary has an `-s` argument to specifically disable user-level site packages.

```bash
python -s -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
```

#### 3: Remove (and avoid future) user-level installs

[The Conda recommendation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#using-pip-in-an-environment) is to avoid `pip install --user` altogether, which would be interpreted that one should remove the `~/.local/lib/python*` folders from your system.

#### 4: Automated Conda environment variable

##### Conda Forge package

[The Conda Forge package `conda-ecosystem-user-package-isolation`](https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-ecosystem-user-package-isolation-feedstock) will automatically set `PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1` during environment activation.

If you would like all environments to have such isolation by default, then consider adding this to the `create_default_packages` configuration list:

```
conda config --add create_default_packages conda-ecosystem-user-package-isolation
```

Note that this package also sets `R_LIBS_USER="-"`, isolating any R environments from user-level packages.

##### Alternative packages

If you want a more granular option, I have also created separate packages that set just the [`PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1`](https://github.com/mfansler/envvar-pythonnousersite-true) and [`PYTHONPATH=""`](https://github.com/mfansler/envvar-pythonpath-null) environment variables, which can be installed with:

```
## set PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1
conda install merv::envvar-pythonnousersite-true

## clear PYTHONPATH
conda install merv::envvar-pythonpath-null
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Your option 3 (remove `~/.local/lib/python*`) perhaps is too aggressive. It seems to me that one should routinely start with `conda activate my-env && export PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1` so that either you import what you have installed in the env or you fail with a meaningful import error. The current behavior is quite tricky...!

Comment: @dariober added another option: automatic environment variable setting via a Conda package. It was kinda a proof-of-concept I've been wanting to try out for awhile. Might be useful for those who still want the user site and want a quick solution to insulate their Conda environment.

Comment: This looked like the answer I wanted, but it doesn't work for me.  When I use the -s option for python (version 3.9.13), the path still has some local directories.  I cannot find the source of those local directories (no conda.pth in my env, nothing obvious anywhere in the env directory tree, etc).

Comment: Following up on my own comment, I found this file that's likely the source of grief: /Users/michael/miniconda3/envs/itr_env_vanilla/lib/python3.9/site-packages/easy-install.pth .  My question is: who installed THAT?

Comment: @MichaelTiemann if it was a Conda package, then the file should be described in the JSON file for the package found in the environment's `conda-meta/` folder. Something like `grep 'easy-install.pth' /Users/michael/miniconda3/envs/itr_env_vanilla/conda-meta/*` should identify the package.

Comment: Option 3 is the easiest one and it has not given me any issues.