# macOS: Cannot import numpy in Matlab since numpy already installed in conda

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, conda

I am trying to import NumPy to Matlab. My version of Python is 3.8.3. Here is what I got when I tried to import NumPy

[image]

Then I am tried to install NumPy but got this

[image]

Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: You have two different Python installations.  The first is the MacOS default one.  The second is the Anaconda installation.  If you're going to use both, then you'll need to install your packages in both places.

Comment: Can I use anaconda env in matlab?

Comment: Other options include using PYTHONPATH or installing packages with `pip install --user`. Though you may want to [isolate your Conda environments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70961159/570918) if using either of those.

Comment: Please post code, not pictures of code. The same applies to error messages.