# Conda Keeps Using Wrong Version of Tensorflow even Installed Correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda, conda

I am creating a different environment on Anaconda to use tensorflow-gpu v2.1. Everytime I try to create an environment with v2.1, when I check the version, it keeps showing me `2.9.0-dev20220329`

Is there any way to get rid of this version?

I followed these steps;

```
conda create -n TF21 python=3.7

conda activate TF21
```

I tried both on different environments;

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.1

conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu==2.1
```

Everytime I check the version of tensorflow with;

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

I keep getting `2.9.0-dev20220329`. I couldn't find a solution yet, I also tried to uninstall/reinstall Anaconda completely but no use.

Is there any way I could get rid of this issue?

Edit - `print(tf.__spec__)` output;

```
ModuleSpec(name='tensorflow',
loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000001CA835B35C8>,
origin='C:\\Users\\Cluster\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\__init__.py',
submodule_search_locations=['C:\\Users\\Cluster\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages\\tensorflow',
'C:\\Users\\Cluster\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\_api\\v2'])
```

Comment: You are not running your code with the python installed in your anaconda env, but with the one installed in `C:\\Users\\Cluster\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python`. How are you running your code? From an IDE, a jupyter notebook or the command line?

Comment: I tried to run it from console, spyder and jupyter all were the same. Funnily, I couldnt find any external path points to python37 in Roaming folder

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70961159/570918

Comment: @merv Thanks, finally fixed the issue. Now even with 1 batch, tensor&keras giving me memory allocation failure on RTX 3060 :)

Comment: @merv why do you close the question? you basically saying that if OP knew whats the problem was (incorrect paths) then he'd probably find the answer in the one you think it is a duplicate. But he didnt know. Its wrong. **It implies you need to know the answer before you post "good" question.**

Comment: @BoppityBop thanks for expressing your concern. However, I'm not convinced the duplicate marking is incorrect. My reasoning was: As detailed in the answer to the other question, packages leaking into the Python session from the user site will take priority. The answer there enumerates ways of preventing such leakage. That solves this question generally, and, after OP pinged me to confirm that it solved the particular issue, I marked it as a duplicate. It was not meant to convey any judgement about the *quality* of question.