# Unexpected behavior after conda force reinstall

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, conda

After downgrading numpy from version 1.22.4 to 1.19.5 with the following command-

```
conda install numpy==1.19.5 --force-reinstall
```

Python behaves unexpectedly.  For example,  `pip list` and `conda list` both show that the version of numpy remains **1.22.4**, yet when starting a shell, the numpy version shows up as **1.19.5**:

```
(tensorflow) demo % python
Python 3.9.12 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Mar 24 2022, 23:24:38) 
[Clang 12.0.1 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.19.5'
```

I have tried deactivating and activating the conda environment. There are no PYTHONPATH environmental variables set, nor is there a module called numpy.py in my directory.  What could explain how the numpy version imported in the shell does *not* correspond to the version displayed by conda list / pip list in the terminal?

Comment: Did you check user site (e.g., `~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`)? That gets prioritized by Python `site` module. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70961159/570918.

Comment: Could you please add the `conda list -n tensorflow --revisions` to the question? Or at least the part showing the `numpy` changes?

Answer (score 2):

Occasionally, I have found that Python can conflict with packages, especially with bigger frameworks, as fully uninstalling it can be difficult. That's the beauty of virtual Python environments, you are able to just create a new one for specific versions, and not have to deal with multiple versions on your native Python install.

It might be worth using another package manager, such as Mamba (https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba), which I have had better experiences with. It also has the benefit of being multi-threaded, and more efficient.

Otherwise, your best bet would probably be to create a new virtual environment, which you can do via (be sure to change the python version if you have a specific use-case, or just get rid of the flag to have the latest version all the time):

```
conda create --name your-name-here python=3.9 -y
```

If you are using Mamba, you can replace any instance of 'conda' that you would otherwise use, for example to install your specific package:

```
mamba install numpy==1.19.5
```

Also, I would recommend using 'Miniconda', as I have had a much better experience with it, just make sure to 'activate' your specific virtual python environment.

Comment: These are nice recommendations, though if the user site is the issue (see comment to OP), even new `python=3.9` environments would still prioritize the user site versions. BTW, if recommending Mamba, consider recommending Mambaforge distributions, rather than Miniconda, since it comes with Mamba and defaults to **conda-forge**.