# Pip uninstall specific version of a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, conda, pypi

My objective is to uninstall a specific version of the **numpy** package using pip, conda, or any other method.  I am using a MacOS 12.0

I am encountering a problem in which `pip list` and `conda list` both show numpy==1.22.4 in the exact same environment, yet for some reason every time I start a python shell with this environment, an older version of numpy is imported.  There are no extraneous files, modules, or env variables that could cause this behavior. There are few posts about *un*installing specific package versions - so my question is two-fold:

a. Is uninstalling a specific package version possible using pip/conda and

b. If not, how can one view the exact location (on the local device) of a package imported in a python shell?

Any advice would be appreciated!

```
(tensorflow) demo % pip show numpy
Name: numpy
Version: 1.22.4

(tensorflow) demo % conda list | grep numpy
numpy                     1.22.4                   pypi_0    pypi

(tensorflow) demo % python
Python 3.9.12 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Mar 24 2022, 23:24:38) 
[Clang 12.0.1 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.19.5'
```

Comment: What does `python -m pip show numpy` show?

Comment: I don't believe a single environment can have 2 versions of the same package, so I'm unclear as to how this could happen.

Comment: Check where it loads from with `np.__spec__`.

Comment: @MB it happens through [user site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70961159/570918) or PYTHONPATH. The default for Python is to prioritize modules in user site.

Answer (score 1):

One can identify whence a module loads by examining the `__spec__` attribute. In this case, you can use

```python
import numpy as np
print(np.__spec__.origin)
```

to identify where the location of the loaded module.

In this case, I strongly suspect this will show it is located in the *user site*, i.e.,

```bash
~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py
```

The default for the Python `site` module is to prioritize user site, and Conda does nothing to block this. Options for handling this are provided in  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70961159/570918).