# AttributeError when exporting conda environment

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, conda

When I try to export one of my environments using `conda env export -n torch > torch.yml` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/onatgirit/anaconda3/bin/conda-env", line 6, in <module>
    from conda_env.cli.main import main
  File "/home/onatgirit/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main.py", line 44, in <module>
    from . import main_create
  File "/home/onatgirit/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main_create.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .. import specs
  File "/home/onatgirit/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_env/specs/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .notebook import NotebookSpec
  File "/home/onatgirit/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_env/specs/notebook.py", line 5, in <module>
    import nbformat
  File "/home/onatgirit/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbformat/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import v1, v2, v3, v4
  File "/home/onatgirit/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbformat/v4/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from .convert import downgrade, upgrade
  File "/home/onatgirit/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbformat/v4/convert.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .. import validator
  File "/home/onatgirit/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbformat/validator.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .json_compat import ValidationError, _validator_for_name, get_current_validator
  File "/home/onatgirit/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbformat/json_compat.py", line 11, in <module>
    import jsonschema
  File "/home/onatgirit/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsonschema/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from jsonschema._format import (
  File "/home/onatgirit/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsonschema/_format.py", line 10, in <module>
    from jsonschema.exceptions import FormatError
  File "/home/onatgirit/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsonschema/exceptions.py", line 158, in <module>
    @attr.s(hash=True)
AttributeError: module 'attr' has no attribute 's'
```

Output for `conda info`:

```
     active environment : None
            shell level : 0
       user config file : /home/onatgirit/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/onatgirit/.condarc
          conda version : 4.13.0
    conda-build version : 3.20.5
         python version : 3.8.13.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=11.6=0
                          __linux=5.13.0=0
                          __glibc=2.31=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /home/onatgirit/anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /home/onatgirit/anaconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/onatgirit/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/onatgirit/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/onatgirit/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/onatgirit/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.13.0 requests/2.27.1 CPython/3.8.13 Linux/5.13.0-44-generic ubuntu/20.04.4 glibc/2.31
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Output for `conda list -n base '(nbformat|jsonschema|attr)'`:

```
    # packages in environment at /home/onatgirit/anaconda3:
    #
    # Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
    attrs                     21.4.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    jsonschema                4.4.0            py38h06a4308_0  
    nbformat                  5.3.0            py38h06a4308_0  
    python-fastjsonschema     2.15.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
```

Output for `conda run -n base python -c 'import attr; print(attr.__spec__)'`:

```
ModuleSpec(name='attr', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fd32b603160>, origin='/home/onatgirit/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/attr.py')
```

The conda version that I'm currently using is 4.13.0 and I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.4 with kernel version 5.13.0-44-generic.

I tried to export other environments as well and had the same problem with them too.

I have also tried to uninstall "attr" and install "attrs" via pip but it didn't have any affect on the situation.

Comment: Maybe try installing `jsonschema` and `attrs` from Conda: `conda install jsonschema attrs` or `conda update jsonschema attrs`.

Comment: I have installed jsonschema but unfortunately the output didn't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is side-loading from user site, which can be seen by how Python has resolved the `attr` module:

```
'/home/onatgirit/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/attr.py'
```

Not sure what is in that file, but it is masking the `attr` module that is expected to be provided by `attrs` packages.

Several options to resolve this can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70961159/570918). For this particular case, if you are not deliberately using the user site, I would recommend removing all `~/.local/lib/python*` directories (i.e., everything installed with `pip install --user`). Otherwise, the simplest solution is probably to do:

```
conda install -n base conda-forge::conda-ecosystem-user-package-isolation
```