# Why conda list h5py and h5py.__version__ are different

Tags: python, conda, h5py

I just wonder why the version of h5py imported in python are different from the version it is installed in conda.

In conda:

```bash
conda activate tensorflow2   # activate environment
conda list h5py
```

Then it shows:

> 2.9.0

But when I import h5py after having typed `python` in the same environment under conda, it shows a different version:

```py
import h5py
h5py.__version__
```

his shows:

> 3.1.0

Why I care about the version of h5py? Because version 2.9.0 seems work ok or load saved tensorflow model in h5 format.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Likely loading from [user site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70961159/570918). Please check `h5py.__spec__`, which will show the path the module is loaded from.

Comment: thanks.  I checked and found the h5py loaded from a python not inside the conda environment.  How to make it loaded from the h5py inside the conda envirionment ?  (I have activated the environemnt inside conda prompt, it is strange).  And by the way, I can not find the another python installed from control panel either.

Comment: After I have removed all the python catelogs installed under c:/users/.../Appdata/Roaming/python, it works. Now the modules imported come from lib under the conda environment.  Many thanks.