# You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 20.3.4 is available

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I want to create a Conda environment with yml file. But when it wants to 'Installing pip dependencies', shows an error:

> "You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 20.3.4 is available"

I updated pip with `pip install --upgrade pip`. My current pip version is: 22.1.2

Also, I installed the version of error (i.e. 20.3.4) but again the same issue happend. My yml file is shown below:

```
name: rig
channels:
- kne  # for pybox2d
- pytorch
- anaconda  # for mkl
- defaults
dependencies:
- pip #>= 22.0
- cython
- ipython  # technically unnecessary
- joblib >= 0.9.4
- lockfile
- mako >= 1.0.6
- matplotlib >= 2.0.2
- mkl >= 2018.0.2  # Need to add explicit dependence for pytorch
- numba >= 0.35.0
- numpy >= 1.11.3
- path.py >= 10.3.1
- pybox2d >= 2.3.1
- python >= 3.5.2
- python-dateutil >= 2.6.1
- pytorch-cpu >= 0.4.1
- scipy >= 1.0.1
- patchelf
- pip:
  - cloudpickle >= 0.5.2
  - gym[all] >= 0.10.5
  - gitpython >= 2.1.7
  - gtimer >= 1.0.0b5
  - pygame >= 1.9.2
  - ipdb  # technically unnecessary
```

I should declare that at first I specified the packages update version but it showed me the error of conflict, so I considered >= logic to install the packages.

Thank you very much in advanced

**Solved: For solving this issue, I created another environment with Conda and installed all packages one by one with Conda or pip.**

Comment: Use `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` instead

Comment: I used, but the same as previous :(

Comment: What Python and Conda version?

Comment: @9769953  python --version:  3.8.10,   conda --version: 4.13.0

Comment: Possibly have `pip` installed in a user site. User-level installations mask environment-local installations. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70958434/unexpected-python-paths-in-conda-environment