# How to compare the shared libraries with the libraries of a conda environment?

Tags: linux, centos, conda

I am looking for a method to compare the shared libraries in Linux (Centox 8) and the libraries of a conda environment.

More specifically, is there a command that allows to see what are the common libraries in both places ? I am asking this because I need to know if there could be some conflict between the system environment and the conda environment.

**[EDIT]** I am asking this, because I have a bug when executing a script, and I need to see if there is no conflict between two version of the **libmagic library** (so one would be in the conda env and the other version would be of the system)

Thank you

Comment: If in doubt, isolate the environment. There are options [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70961159/570918) that don't require any changes to system- or user-level sites.

Comment: @merv thanks for the link merv, I updated my post with a more specific demand