# Why are my conda installed package versions inside the same environment different as the administrator?

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, conda, numba

I am working on a project using numba (or trying to at least) and it needs a numpy version <= 1.21.
So I created a new environment as the administrator under `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs`. I then installed numpy as version 1.21.5 via

`conda install numpy==1.21.5`.

After checking the version by activating the environment (which is in the expected path), running a python shell, importing numpy through `import numpy as np` and checking `np.__version__=='1.21.5'` (which evaluates to `True`) I switched back to cmd but this time not as the administrator.
I again activated the same environment, started python, imported numpy and suddenly got `np.__version__=='1.22.4'`.

This even means that `import numba` works as the administrator, yet the same command throws an `ImportError: Numba needs NumPy 1.21 or less`  when run 'normally'.

I have a second, working environment in the same directory that does have this problem too yet it is telling me numpy version 1.22.3 as administrator and version 1.22.4 as a normal user and it does not matter much because I don't need numba in it.

Does anybody have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Add to the question the output of `python -c 'import numpy; print(numpy.__path__)'`. Most likely loading from a user site, i.e., duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/70958434/570918

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. the package path was indeed someting in my personal folder under `myUser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages` . I renamed the folder to prevent access and now it is using the wanted version from the correct path! Thank you again!

Comment: Yes, that is the user site.