# How can I solve an import error (dlopen) when trying to import python library seaborn? (M1 mac)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, conda, python-import

When trying to import the seaborn package I get the below error.

The package is installed in my environment. Initially installed using `conda install seaborn`. After that didnt work I followed this method specified here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-seaborn-on-macos/

Any help would be greatly appreciated all other packages tried work fine.

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/name/folder/folder/folder/seaborn-0.11.2/seaborn/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .rcmod import *  # noqa: F401,F403
  File "/Users/name/folder/folder/folder/seaborn-0.11.2/seaborn/rcmod.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import palettes
  File "/Users/name/folder/folder/folder/seaborn-0.11.2/seaborn/palettes.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .utils import desaturate, get_color_cycle
  File "/Users/name/folder/folder/folder/labs/seaborn-0.11.2/seaborn/utils.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy import stats
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/TU_working_with_data/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py", line 453, in <module>
    from ._stats_py import *
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/TU_working_with_data/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/_stats_py.py", line 38, in <module>
    from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/TU_working_with_data/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/spatial/__init__.py", line 104, in <module>
    from ._qhull import *
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/TU_working_with_data/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/spatial/_qhull.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: '@rpath/liblapack.3.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/TU_working_with_data/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/spatial/_qhull.cpython-39-darwin.so'
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/TU_working_with_data/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/spatial/../../../../liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/TU_working_with_data/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/spatial/../../../../liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/TU_working_with_data/bin/../lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/TU_working_with_data/bin/../lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file)
```

**Update**

`conda list -n TU_working_with_data (seaborn|scipy)`

outputs:

```
# packages in environment at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/TU_working_with_data:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
scipy                     1.8.1            py39h14896cb_2    conda-forge
seaborn                   0.11.2                   pypi_0    pypi
```

Comment: The fact that it's specifically liblapack.3.dylib that it can't find is critical enough to justify putting it in the title.

Comment: Also, have you tried to figuring out where that library comes from, and what you'd need to install to get it? (Personally, my preferred approach is to avoid Homebrew, avoid conda, and stick to Nix for package management -- with brew you're trusting the package authors to model dependencies correctly; the Nix way has less room for human error to create subtly-wrong packages via undeclared dependencies).

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.

Comment: The paths in the error don't look like their for anaconda, and seaborn should already be installed as part of the anaconda distribution.

Comment: Thank you will have a look at Anaconda distribution.

Comment: Please add output of `conda list -n TU_working_with_data '(seaborn|scipy)'` to the question. Also, the suggestion to use Anaconda distribution is a bit off. One can create an "Anaconda-like" environment by installing the `anaconda` metapackage - no need to use the installer. That is, `conda create -n foo -c anaconda anaconda python=3.9` will create a Python 3.9 environment with all the Anaconda distribution packages.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be that `seaborn` is being loaded from outside the environment and therefore has different dynamic library links. There is [advice in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70961159/570918) on how to isolate environments, ranging from deleting user-level sites to enabling isolation on a per-environment basis.

Also, be sure that `seaborn` is actually installed in the environment itself (i.e., check `conda list -n TU_working_with_data seaborn`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes seaborn is loaded into my environment. I

`conda list -n TU_working_with_data seaborn                                                                                                           
# packages in environment at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/TU_working_with_data:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
seaborn                   0.11.2                   pypi_0    pypi `

Comment: @Sean okay, so that shows that the environment has a copy, but the output in the question body indicates that one is not loaded. Have you tried following the advice in other answer to block loading user site modules? Were there still other problems? Please update the original question body with all additional information (rather than putting code in comments).