# How can I prevent Opencv from using a wrong path after installation / ImportError

Tags: python, opencv, installation, pip, conda

There are two other Python versions on the system: 2.7 and - in a different environment - 3.7 including Opencv installed.

For some reasons I need another python version (3.8). Therefore I installed python 3.8 in a separate environment and after activating this environment I installed Opencv in this environment:

I open a miniforge3 promt (which is NOT installed on partition c:\ ) change to the miniforge3 path on partition d:\ and enter:

```
conda create -n Python38 python=3.8 NumPy xarray netCDF4 holoviews hvplot bokeh pandas matplotlib IPython ipywidgets datashader
```

after that I installed opencv among some other packages:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

I check the versions with:

```
(Python38) D:\mypath\miniforge3\envs\Python38>pip list |findstr opencv
opencv-contrib-python 4.6.0.66
opencv-python 4.6.0.66
opencv-python-headless 4.6.0.66
```

So it should not be due to incompatibility between versions, as is often found on the net. However, I still get an import error:

```
ImportError: cannot import the name '_registerMatType' from 'cv2.cv2' (c:\python38\lib\site-packages\cv2\cv2.cp38-win_amd64.pyd)
```

This points to the partition c:\
I think this is strange and is certainly indicative of the error. I don't understand this yet. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: welcome. please take the [tour] and review [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Do not install multiple package variants of OpenCV.

Install **exactly one** variant.

Remove them all, then install one of them.

All of them contain the base modules.

Use only the packages on PyPI (installable with pip). Those are **official** packages.

Comment: '@christoph-rackwitz (sorry-that @ doesn't work like it used to) Thanks for pointing that out, but in this case I'm sorry that I have to install two environments that each access opencv. Is it possible to configure the two environments to access the same installation of opencv?

Comment: you'll have to use virtual environments, and _in there_ install exactly one package (in each environment). do not install multiple packages in any environment. virtual environments are made for these situations, to limit the scope. I don't know if system-wide installed packages affect a virtual environment.

Comment: Just FYI: The default behavior for Conda virtual environments is that user site packages are included and prioritized, which is simply the default behavior of the `site` module. There are [options to customize the site loading behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70961159/570918), e.g., if one wants more stringent isolation.