# ubuntu20.04：The file is damaged, resulting in the inability of conda to connect to the network

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, anaconda

My computer environment is ubuntu20.04，conda 22.9.0. I'm Unable to execute the [conda install] and [conda env list] commands. However, I can execute the [conda activate lf] command. When the [conda install ] and [conda env list] command  is executed, this error prompt appears

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wpu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from requests import ConnectionError, HTTPError, Session
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wpu/anaconda3/bin/conda-env", line 6, in <module>
    from conda_env.cli.main import main
  File "/home/wpu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    import conda.exports  # noqa
  File "/home/wpu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/exports.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import plan  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/wpu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/plan.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .core.index import LAST_CHANNEL_URLS, _supplement_index_with_prefix
  File "/home/wpu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "/home/wpu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .path_actions import CacheUrlAction, ExtractPackageAction
  File "/home/wpu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/path_actions.py", line 34, in <module>
    from ..gateways.connection.download import download
  File "/home/wpu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests import ConnectionError, HTTPError, Session
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

I don't know what causes these problem. Can you help me?

I thought the [requests] module was not installed, but when I execute the [pip install requests] command, the following prompt appears:

```
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.22.0)
```

Executing the pip statement smoothly。

Comment: Try upgrading pip once `pip install --upgrade pip` & restart anaconda once

Comment: Think about upgrading Ubuntu as well.  We're up to 22.04 - Jammy Jellyfish.  https://releases.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Is this a fresh install of Anaconda3? Possibly due to [leaking of user site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70958434/570918).

Comment: I updated pip.But the problem has not been solved.Not the latest installation of Anaconda3.

Comment: When I execute these two commands【pip -V】【python -V】 in the base environment, the displayed version of python is different. Is there a problem?

【pip -V  】        
pip 22.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)        

【python -V     】     
Python 3.9.13