# Conda environment using incorrect module because of order os sys.path

Tags: python, conda, sys.path

I am using conda version 4.14.0. When I activate a conda environment I can see that the current numpy module is 1.22.3

```
conda list | grep -i numpy
numpy                     1.22.3           py39hc58783e_2    conda-forge
```

When I run python in the conda environment and load numpy it shows version 1.19.1

```
Python 3.9.12 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Mar 24 2022, 23:25:59)
[GCC 10.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.19.5'
```

Looking at the sys.path locations I see that it is searching my local account site packages before the environment site-packages, how can this order be updated?

```
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/opt/tljh/user/lib/python39.zip', 
'/opt/main/user/lib/python3.9', 
'/opt/main/user/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', 
'/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages', 
'/opt/main/user/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
```

Thank you for your help.

I cannot find where these variables are added through conda.

Comment: Try doing this in a new environment after manually installing the `numpy` version you intend to and see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user site packages (at `~/.local`) remaining available is the default behaviour of conda envs, and even issues requesting adding an *option* to disable that have been repeatedly closed by conda maintainers ([example](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/394)).

It is an unfortunate decision from Conda that the user site is included by default. You can exclude it from `sys.path` by setting an [environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONNOUSERSITE):

```
export PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1
```

That sounds hacky but it is actually the recommended workaround from conda themselves ([ref](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7671#issuecomment-414694331)).

Or, you can do what I do and just keep the user site totally empty, to avoid such issues without needing to mess around with env vars. Uninstall everything from `~/.local` and use separate venvs for everything.

```
~/.local/bin/python3.9 -m pip uninstall -r <(~/.local/bin/python3.9 -m pip freeze)
```

You can use a project like [pipx](https://pypa.github.io/pipx/) as a replacement to install any utilities which should be globally available, this avoids polluting the user site (and conda envs) with their dependencies.

Watch [#7707](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7707) (*make python user site-packages isolation in .local directory configurable*) for possible future developments from conda here.

Comment: This is very useful and nicely documented info, but I've been using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70958434/570918) as a canonical duplicate for such "why are user packages taking precedence?" questions. Perhaps consider posting this info there.