# conda's behavior differs between two identical pc's using the same version

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, anaconda, conda

My colleague and I are having a head-scratcher moment. We built an internal library that are trying to get working on two machines. The machines are nearly identical in hardware spec.

On my machine i can do this:

```
>conda create  --no-default-packages -n library_test_env python=3.8
>conda activate library_test_env
>pip install git+https_link_to_repository
```

Which will then install the library and the dependencies. When I do `conda list` it doesn't list all the dependencies, it does however show some of them but not our own library. My colleague gets a much longer list, which does contains the dependencies and the library.

When i do `pip list` i get a much longer list than my colleague, which includes the library and the remaining dependencies.

Here is the catch; a specific function in the library uses sqlalchemy to connect to the company database and run a query. The query returns a timeseries which contains a UTC timestamp column.

On my machine the dtype of this column is `datetime64` as you would expect, on his machine it is read as an `object`. Which causes the logic to fail.

We are scratching our heads here. Apart from the different behavior of conda on our machines I just realised he is using windows 11 and I am using windows 10. Apart from the dependencies showing up differently when using `conda list` and `pip list` the listed versions are identical.

What could be a possible cause of this?

Comment: Are you sure you are running pip in the context of your conda env? My guess is no.

Comment: Someone probably did `pip install --user`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70958434/unexpected-python-paths-in-conda-environment/70961159#70961159

Comment: @merv this was it!