# How to uninstall a specific version of pip from my linux system?

Tags: linux, pip

To update pip, I inadvertently ran `pip3 install --upgrade pip`, without `sudo`.

So I get this warning:

`WARNING: The scripts pip, pip3, pip3.10 and pip3.11 are installed in '/home/myhome/.local/bin' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.`

So, I now have two versions of pip, one for the root and one for me:

`pip 22.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.10)`

`pip 23.2.1 from /home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)`

This is messy!

How to get rid of this newly and wrongly installed pip version?

Comment: it's easy, you can use the `pip` command with the `uninstall` option like this : `pip uninstall pip`

Comment: To remove a specific version of pip, you can use the `pip uninstall` command followed by the version number,for example like this : `pip uninstall pip==23.2.1` and If the method I mentioned was helpful to you and solved your problem, please let me know so that I can write it as an answer to your question. This way, you can choose it as the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some other options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70958434/unexpected-python-paths-in-conda-environment/70961159#70961159), but you could also use `python[version] -m pip uninstall pip`, or `/path/to/relevant/python -m pip uninstall pip`, as in `python3.10 -m pip uninstall pip` or `/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip uninstall pip`. You could also go to the appropriate directories and remove the files manually, as in `rm ~/.local/bin/pip && rm -rf ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip`. Or you could leave the extras and set your default, eg `alias pip='/usr/local/bin/pip3'` or a script in `PATH` that calls the correct version.