# Miniconda3 - Base is full with packages that I didn't installed

Tags: conda, miniconda

Miniconda 3 on Ubuntu 20.04

My base has packages that I never installed in the base. When creating a new environment, this new environment comes with base packages, which theoretically it shouldn't.

I already removed Miniconda3 and installed it again and the problem persists the same. Has anyone else experienced this and know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70958434/570918. Alternatively, be aware that Conda brings its own dependencies, and base needs both `python` and `conda`, which need things like cryptography, compression, and ssh shared libraries.

Comment: What is installed? Please edit the question to show how you determine that "*base is full with packages*". Also, please do some testing to determine *where* some of them are installed. For example, `python -c 'import pandas; print(pandas.__path__)'`. You very likely have a user site-packages for the Python version matching the Conda **base** and creating a Python 3.11 environment simply avoids that.

Comment: @merv, you are right, that post is related and help me a little to solve that problem at all. Thx, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running e.g. `conda create --name test python=3.11`, the `pip freeze` from that environment shows me nothing. It doesn't solve the problem, but it works around the situation to work in an isolated environment.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Also what other way do you create an environment other than `conda create --name xxx`?

Comment: Hi, @topsail ! When I just specifying python version like `conda create --name [env-name] python=3.9` I can get a clean environment. Otherwise, if I just execute `conda create --name [env-name]` so I got a new environment but with many packages from base (and I didn't install anything in base).

Comment: I *think* I have also noticed this behavior recently with Anaconda. Not 100% sure. Are you sure you are using *Miniconda*? Miniconda generally doesn't install a lot of packages in base (Anaconda does, though). When you say many packages from base - how many is *many* (10, 20, 100, 200?)

Comment: @topsail, I'm 100% sure that I'm not using Anaconda, just Miniconda3. What about the quantity of packages, I don't know why, but it's just back to normal, and I dunno how I did that.