# Trying to use umap-learn (import umap) but I get "Numba needs NumPy 1.24 or less"

Tags: numpy, pip, conda, numba

I am facing this problem and I read a lot that the solution is downgrading numpy, but is not enough. It is indeed related to umap-learn installation. Currently, I have numpy 1.23.5 and numba 0.57.1 and still it shows me the error message: Numba needs NumPy 1.24 or less.

I have installed numpy, scipy, scikit-learn and umap-learn through conda-forge but I also tried with pip, and no luck. I uninstall numpy and umap-learn and then install umap-learn again (with conda-forge). During the dependencies' installation, it installed numpy 1.24.4 and numba. Then I downgraded numpy (with conda-forge too) to 1.23.5 and still the same error message.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the environment you are trying to install in? Do you have NumPy installed in a user site that is leaking in? E.g., https://stackoverflow.com/q/70958434/570918

Comment: In both cases, using miniconda and pip, I tried in a new virtual environment.

Comment: Please show the output of `conda list` for the environment. Also, provide the result from `python -c 'import numpy; print(numpy.__path__)'` so we can see where it is loading from. Please edit the question to show this information.