# How to install and run Jupyter Notebook 7 using Conda?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

Despite Jupyter Notebook 7 being a [stable release](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html) for [a while](https://blog.jupyter.org/announcing-jupyter-notebook-7-8d6d66126dcf) now, `conda install -c conda-forge notebook` still appears to install the old version. A quick `jupyter notebook --version` still shows 6.4.11. What could I be doing wrong?

Edit: I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. You can always go to the page that describes the current version at [anaconda.org/conda-forge/notebook](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/notebook) to check yourself. You'll see there it says version 7.0.5 has been there for just over 24 hours now. Then you can click on the 'Files' tab to see that the 7.0 and above versions have been there for over two months now. You maybe have something that is interfering with it solving things to use the latest version?

Comment: For those following along, theres a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77309960/8508004), where the OP had seen a different recommendation.

Comment: So what is the difference here and the other question? That this is **linux** instead of **osx**? That seems fairly trivial and neither of these questions give details on the environment that is trying to install into. Without that, I'm close voting.

Comment: Also, have you verified that you don't have `notebook` installed in a user site? e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/q/70958434/570918

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could explicitly install a specific version of Jupyter lab and notebook using -
`conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab=4.0.7 notebook=7.0.6`

You can get the latest version of both from conda-forge, links for both as follows -

- [Notebook](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/notebook/files)
- [JupyterLab](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/jupyterlab/files)