# Why do I see a global version of Gnuradio (i.e. 3.8) when using a conda environment with a more recent local version (i.e. 3.10)?

Tags: conda, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, mamba

I am working on a Ubuntu 20.04 system with several users that has Gnuradio v. 3.8 installed. I am trying to use some software that requires v. 3.10. Rather than wait to get group approval to update our shared version, I created a local environment for myself following the directions given at [Recommended Gnuradio Conda Install](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=CondaInstall#Installation_using_radioconda_(recommended)). :

```
(base) me@jk4$:~$ conda create -n radioconda -c conda-forge -c ryanvolz --only-deps radioconda
```

However, when I run gnuradio-companion, it opens v 3.8:

```
(radioconda) me@jk4:~/Projects$ gnuradio-companion
<<< Welcome to GNU Radio Companion 3.8.1.0 >>>
```

I've checked to see which gnuradio-companion I am trying to execute:

```
(radioconda) me@jk4:~/Projects$ which gnuradio-companion
/home/me/mambaforge/envs/radioconda/bin/gnuradio-companion
```

and see that I am using the version in my conda environment, which just makes things more confusing.

I double checked my env folder for any gnuradio files, and saw plenty of files with 3.10 in their names, but none with 3.8. I then tried running the binary in my environment directly, but without success:

```
(radioconda) me@jk4:~$ /home/me/mambaforge/envs/radioconda/bin/gnuradio-companion 
<<< Welcome to GNU Radio Companion 3.8.1.0 >>>
```

I next tried installing the radioconda environment on my personal laptop, which doesn't have gnuradio installed and saw what I expected:

```
(radioconda) me@mymachine:~$ gnuradio-companion 
<<< Welcome to GNU Radio Companion 3.10.7.0 >>>
```

So, I know creating the radioconda environment gives me the gnuradio 3.10 files. What I can't figure out is why I can't use them instead of the system gnuradio files.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70958434/570918

Comment: what operating system are you running this on?

Comment: @MarcusMüller - Ubuntu 20.04