# Uninstall package located in /Library/Python/3.9/bin

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, streamlit

I would like to install a package (streamlit) only in a `conda` environment, not system-wide. However, when I go to `pip install` it in the environment, it says that the requirements were already satisfied in `/Users/adamg/Library/Python/3.9/bin`. How do I remove this instance, so that streamlit is installed only within conda environments?

Here is my output when I install it in a conda environment:

```
(streamlit0) 22:28:34 ~
○ pip install streamlit
zsh: correct 'streamlit' to '.streamlit' [nyae]? n
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting streamlit
  Using cached streamlit-1.31.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.1 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: altair<6,>=4.0 in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from streamlit) (5.2.0)
...
Using cached streamlit-1.31.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.4 MB)
Installing collected packages: streamlit
  WARNING: The script streamlit is installed in '/Users/adamg/Library/Python/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed streamlit-1.31.0
```

Comment: Did you install pip with conda? Its usually required if I want to use pip packages with a conda environment. [docs](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#using-pip-in-an-environment). Otherwise you will have to use the conda package from [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/streamlit).

Comment: I honestly don't remember. Is there a way to reinstall pip with conda?

Comment: You install it with `conda` in each environment like shown in the [documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#using-pip-in-an-environment) I linked.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. It's not like I can do a universal setting for conda. Anyway, using conda-forge worked. Thank you!

Comment: FYI, [user site will trump Conda installs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70958434/570918). You should still consider deleting the user site, or at least remove that package (e.g., `pip uninstall streamlit` *without Conda environment activated*).

Comment: I tried uninstalling it outside of a conda environment. I then created a new environment, installed pip inside that environment, and then used pip to install streamlit. I still got the same message about it being in /User. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

**Without** activating conda, try uninstalling Streamlit.
After that, check to make sure it was successfully uninstalled with the command `pip list`, this approach will list all your installed packages.
If you still see the Streamlit package among the listed packages, try removing it manual using the `rm` command followed by the path:

```
rm /Users/adamg/Library/Python/3.9/bin/streamlit
```

Then make sure your conda env is **activated** before you proceed to install the package again.