# ImportError: cannot import name '_initialize_variables' from 'keras.src.backend'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, conda

I'm using Jupyter Notebook inside Visual Studio Code with a Conda environment that uses CUDA, but when trying to import specific modules from tf.keras I get an import error, even thought tensorflow and tensorflow.keras import just fine.

I'm using Tensorflow 2.15.0, here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import layers

inputs = layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
x = layers.Flatten()(inputs)
x = layers.Dense(128, 'relu')(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(10, 'softmax')(x)

model = Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='Adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

It returns this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 2
      1 import tensorflow as tf
----> 2 from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
      3 from tensorflow.keras import layers
      5 inputs = layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))

File c:\Users\Little Red Wagon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\api\_v2\keras\__init__.py:3
      1 """AUTOGENERATED. DO NOT EDIT."""
----> 3 from keras.api._v2.keras import __internal__
      4 from keras.api._v2.keras import activations
      5 from keras.api._v2.keras import applications

File c:\Users\Little Red Wagon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\api\_v2\keras\__init__.py:3
      1 """AUTOGENERATED. DO NOT EDIT."""
----> 3 from keras.api._v2.keras import __internal__
      4 from keras.api._v2.keras import activations
      5 from keras.api._v2.keras import applications

File c:\Users\Little Red Wagon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\api\_v2\keras\__internal__\__init__.py:3
      1 """AUTOGENERATED. DO NOT EDIT."""
----> 3 from keras.api._v2.keras.__internal__ import backend
      4 from keras.api._v2.keras.__internal__ import layers
      5 from keras.api._v2.keras.__internal__ import losses
...
      1 """AUTOGENERATED. DO NOT EDIT."""
----> 3 from keras.src.backend import _initialize_variables as initialize_variables
      4 from keras.src.backend import track_variable

ImportError: cannot import name '_initialize_variables' from 'keras.src.backend' (c:\Users\Little Red Wagon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\__init__.py)
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...
```

The strange this is that each of these modules works fine from the tensorflow library, as I tried using them without importing them as their own package:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, 'relu')(x)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, 'softmax')(x)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='Adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

This worked fine and returned the expected results:

```
Model: "functional_5"
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Layer (type)                    ┃ Output Shape              ┃    Param # ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ input_layer_2 (InputLayer)      │ (None, 28, 28, 1)         │          0 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼────────────┤
│ flatten_2 (Flatten)             │ (None, 784)               │          0 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼────────────┤
│ dense_5 (Dense)                 │ (None, 128)               │    100,480 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼────────────┤
│ dense_6 (Dense)                 │ (None, 10)                │      1,290 │
└─────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────┴────────────┘
 Total params: 101,770 (397.54 KB)
 Trainable params: 101,770 (397.54 KB)
 Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)
```

I've tried updating tensorflow and keras, but the problem persists, and I'm not quite sure why it works fine from the tensorflow package but has trouble being imported separately. I also tried just importing the keras library from tensorflow and that worked fine as well.

Comment: It shows packages are getting loaded from a user site (`c:\Users\Little Red Wagon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras`). Conda has problems with user sites (they take priority) and recommends not to use them. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/70958434/570918