# Python module throws an error that i'm not sure how to solve

Tags: python, conda

I have a python module named `pyvoro` which I have installed in a conda environment, and intend to use it on a HPC cluster. Unfortunately, I get the following error when running my script using the module:

```
File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pyvoro
  File "/home/hpc/51/dickson5/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyvoro/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import voroplusplus
ImportError: /home/hpc/51/dickson5/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/voroplusplus.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length
```

I believe this is something to do with a mismatch between the libraries used by python and the libraries used in the module itself? Any help would be really appreciated.

I've tried reinstalling the package, and also checked that it works on my local machine (which it does). I have also tried initialising a fresh conda environment and installing the library, but still with no success.

Comment: I removed the apologies from your question. SO is for questions to be asked. You might [edit] and change to a more descriptive and unique title, though.

Comment: You see, [pyvoro](https://pypi.org/project/pyvoro/) was last updated in Sep 2014, which is likely to be the reason it's breaking. I'd try and find a [more recent](https://pypi.org/search/?q=voronoi) package to replace it.

Comment: Can you show us the `test.py` file? You should always provide also the python code for the sake of completeness and reproducibility.

Comment: @Jeyekomon the stack trace seems sufficient here, i.e., `import pyvoro` fails because `import voroplusplus` fails.

Comment: Perhaps not the immediate issue, but please note that when working with Conda environments it is strongly discouraged to install anything into a user-site (i.e., `~/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`), since [it masks the Conda environment packages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70958434/570918), which can lead to library incompatibilities. If mixing Pip and Conda, best practice is to use a YAML to define the environment; doing `pip install --user` is the *worst practice*. I would recommend recreating the environment from a YAML - at which point I'd be willing to revisit if the issue persists.

Comment: Also, this package never was tested for Python 3.6. I'd guess Python 2.7 was the dominant deployment at the time, and I'd make sure to that a then-contemporary version of Cython is installed, especially since the error appears to be with Cython-compiled code.