# Conda environment inherit my global packages

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

When I create a conda environment it inherits all the packages I have on my system.
My OS is Windows 10.

If I run the `where python` on my conda environment I get the following:

```
C:\Users\Jordi\anaconda3\envs\mmpose-env\python.exe
C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe
C:\Users\Jordi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

Comment: Did you activate the new conda environment?  `conda activate <env name>`

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70958434/unexpected-python-paths-in-conda-environment/70961159#70961159

Comment: Yes, I activated it. That's why it's strange.