`conda list` mis-reports package version
How come
$ conda list --show-channel-urls dateutil
# packages in environment at .../miniconda3/envs/c312:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
python-dateutil           2.9.0post0      py312haa95532_0  defaults

but
$ python -c 'import dateutil; print(dateutil.__version__); print(dateutil.__path__)'
2.8.2
['.../miniconda3/envs/c312/Lib/site-packages/dateutil']

and
cat $(python -c 'import dateutil; print(dateutil.__path__[0])')/_version.py
# file generated by setuptools_scm
# don't change, don't track in version control
...
__version__ = version = '2.8.2'
__version_tuple__ = version_tuple = (2, 8, 2)

Judging by

.../miniconda3/envs/c312/Lib/site-packages/dateutil/tz/tz.py: DeprecationWarning: datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp() is deprecated...

the actually used code is 2.8.2.
PS. Just in case (cf Unexpected Python paths in Conda environment):
$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['',
 '.../miniconda3/envs/c312/python312.zip',
 '.../miniconda3/envs/c312/DLLs',
 '.../miniconda3/envs/c312/Lib',
 '.../miniconda3/envs/c312',
 '.../miniconda3/envs/c312/Lib/site-packages',
 '__editable__.FX-0.0.0.finder.__path_hook__',
 '__editable__.PyApp-36.finder.__path_hook__',
 '.../miniconda3/envs/c312/Lib/site-packages/win32',
 '.../miniconda3/envs/c312/Lib/site-packages/win32/lib',
 '.../miniconda3/envs/c312/Lib/site-packages/Pythonwin']

(I replaced backslashes in paths with normal slashes by hand to protect my eyes).
Reported as conda list mis-reports package version.

Determine where it is loading from, e.g., python -c 'import dateutil; print(dateutil.__path__)'. Possibly it's loading from a user site (which takes priority), rather than something misreported by Conda. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70958434/570918

@merv: thank you, I edited the question to include your suggestions.

@9769953: thank you, please see edit. Do you think I should report this as a bug in conda?

Nice find! Looks like Anaconda's recipe itself had version: 2.9.0post0, but the tarball given to source.url was still pointing at 2.8.2. So, it's a recipe bug specifically on defaults channel (conda-forge version is as it should be).
