# Remove pillow package from anaconda environment

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, python-imaging-library, uninstallation

I would like to uninstall the `pillow` package from my conda environment. The problem is that although the package is listed, I can't uninstall it. First I check if the package is in the environment:

```
conda list pillow

# Name    Version    Build   Channel
pillow    10.0.0    pypi_0     pypi
```

So we can see that the package is installed in the environment. To remove the package I tried the following:

```
conda remove pillow
```

Which returns:

```
PackageNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
 - pillow
```

This is surprising because we can see that it is installed. As I understand the `Channel` is `pypi` which means that I have mixed up `pip` and `conda`. So according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404007/conda-wont-remove-package), I have to uninstall `pillow` using `pip` like this:

```
pip uninstall pillow
```

This works, when checking `pip list` there is no `pillow` package anymore. But when I try again to remove the package from the `conda` environment I get the same error. So I was wondering if anyone know how to uninstall a package from your `conda` environment in this case?

---

Please note: I use windows.

Comment: Even after `pip uninstall` `Pillow` shows up in `conda list`? Does it show in `pip list` or `python -m pip list`?

Comment: Hi @FlyingTeller, After using `pip uninstall Pillow`, pillow still shows up on `conda list`. It doesn't show in both `pip list` and `python -m pip list`.

Comment: Does the first entry that is returned from `where python` point to `python.exe` from your current conda env, or somewhere outside of it?

Comment: @FlyingTeller, When I run `where python` in my conda environment, it returns nothing?

Comment: But you can still run python? That sounds odd... What is printed when you do `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"`

Comment: @FlyingTeller, That returns: `C:\Users\Quinten\.conda\envs\my_env\python.exe`.

Comment: That rules out that there are multiple python versions at play here. Since `python` seems to be associated with your conda env and `python -m pip show` does not show `pillow`, then it sees to be removed from the `pip` side of things. Something is still convincing `conda` that there is a `pip` installed `Pillow` in your env. Is there anything in `C:\Users\Quinten\.conda\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages` named `Pillow`?

Comment: @FlyingTeller, Yes `pillow.py` and `pillow.cpython-310.pyc`

Comment: back them up and then just delete them and see if that solves your issue. That is not a complete Pillow installation anymore, maybe `pip` messed up uninstall for some odd reason. There is also no folder `PIL`?

Comment: @FlyingTeller, Indeed there is no `PIL` folder.

Comment: That makes me even more convinced this is an uncomplete uninstall. Did removing these files make a difference?

Comment: @FlyingTeller, Unfortunately when checking `conda list` `pillow` is still there.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you choose the correct Python version. For example, if pillow is in python 3.11 packages and you are using 3.10 python pip, pip may throw such an error because it doesn't see pillow in python 3.10 package.

Comment: OP is seeing an error from Conda, not from pip.